# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a float value which I need to divide by the number of days calculated as follow:

```
import timedelta
import datetime
days_cur_cycle=abs(start_date.date()-today_date.date())
//start_date and today_date are datetime objects
x=3.09
y=x/days_cur_cycle`
```

Here I am getting the following error

```
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'datetime.timedelta'**
```

Somebody please help me to calculate it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you will need something like :
days_cur_cycle=abs( (start_date.date()-today_date.date())**.days** )